# making asynchronous blocks run before other code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to fetch a video from the ALAssetLibrary so that I can do stuff with it. I'm using blocks to do it:

```
NSMutableArray *assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

NSLog(@"library allocated");

// Enumerate just the photos and videos group by using ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos.

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

    NSLog(@"Begin enmeration");

    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];

    NSLog(@"Filter by videos");

    [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[group numberOfAssets]-1]

                            options:0

                         usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {

                             NSLog(@"Asset retrieved");

                             if (alAsset) {

                                 ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];

                                 NSURL *url = [representation url];

                                 AVAsset *recentVideo = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

                                 [assets addObject:recentVideo];

                                 NSLog(@"Asset added to array");

                             } 
                         }];
}

AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

NSLog(@"creating source");
AVURLAsset* sourceAsset = [assets objectAtIndex:0];
```

When I run the code the blocks get skipped over and the program crashes when I try to access the element in the array because it doesn't exist. I've been told that it's because the blocks are asynchronous but I'm not sure how to make them run before everything else does. performSelectorOnMainThread sounds like it might do it but I can't really find anything that explains how I would go about doing so with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want

```
AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

NSLog(@"creating source");
AVURLAsset* sourceAsset = [assets objectAtIndex:0];
```

to happen after the enumeration of the `group`, then put it inside the first Block, but after that enumeration:

```
AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
__block AVURLAsset* sourceAsset = nil;
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

    // snip...

    [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[group numberOfAssets]-1]
                            options:0
                         usingBlock:^{
                             // snip... 
                         }];
    sourceAsset = [assets objectAtIndex:0];
    // Now do other things that depend on sourceAsset being set 
}];
```

The `__block` keyword allows the pointer to be set to a new object inside the Block; variables are not re-assignable otherwise.

Comment: I do need it like that but there's also a bunch of other code that has to run after it as well. I'm thinking it's probably best to just try and put the enumeration into its own function where I also assign the source asset and then do all of the other stuff after that, but I'm worried that even if I put it into a function it'll still act all weird. Guess I'll never know 'til I try, though.